# How to reuse the jsf component parameters?

Tags: jsf

I have code

```
    <p:column id="columnLastComment" headerText="LAST COMM" width="80"
    styleClass="long-field" filterStyleClass="flt-hidden"
    style="#{alarmTable.getDisplayStatus('columnLastComment')}"
    sortBy="#{alarm.lastComment}" filterBy="#{alarm.lastComment}">
    <h:outputText value="#{alarm.lastComment}" />
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="LAST COMM" title="Last Comment"
            styleClass="tableHeader-fontSize" />
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

How i can use id of column in style value? example -
`style="#{alarmTable.getDisplayStatus('[id of this column]')}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you could get away with the implicit EL variable `#{component}` to get the current component, like so:

```
<h:outputText id="foo" styleClass="#{bean.styleClass(component.id)}" />
```

But, unfortunately, the `UIColumn` component has a special treatment. The `#{component}` refers the parent `UIData` component instead, which would in your case be the `<p:dataTable>`.

So, you've really to repeat it (like as you're already doing for the phrase "lastComment". You could maybe make it less painful by using a property of `#{alarm}`.

Comment: I need dynamicly set style "display:none" for about 25 column, but i need save this column in client size for use lazy filtering.

Comment: And `#{alarm}` var in `<p:dataTable/>  <p:dataTable id="alarmTableId" value="#{alarmTable.alarms}"
 draggableColumns="true" resizableColumns="true" var="alarm"
 selection="#{alarmTable.selectedAlarm}" selectionMode="multiple"
  paginator="true" rows="50" emptyMessage="No alarms"
 sortBy="#{alarm.alarmTs}" sortOrder="descending"
 widgetVar="alarmTableWidget"  lazy="true" />`